# TypError raised by Pandas module when fitting a Scikit-Learn GridSearchCV

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, anaconda, typeerror

Been plagued by this bug for a while now and could use some hive-mind help to (hopefully) catch something I'm missing.

**tl;dr version**

Pandas is raising a TypeError when I pass scikit-learn GridSearchCV ndarrays of floats to train on.

**full version**

I'm using an sklearn [GridSearchCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV.html) object to fit a 1D list of float target variables scaled between 0.0 and 1.0 to a 2D list of float feature variables (input variables) also scaled between 0 and 1. Both lists have the same number of samples.

The abbreviated code where I pass my training data to GridSearchCV.fit() is as follows:

```
# the training data are attributes of a model class defined elsewhere
model.X_scaled # ndarray of feature data of shape (N_samples, N_features)
model.Y_scaled # ndarray target data of length N_samples

# setup the GridSearchCV instance
search = grid_search.GridSearchCV(estimator = svr,
                                          param_grid = params, # C and epsilon parameters are set elsewhere in a dict
                                          n_jobs = self.parallel_processes,
                                          scoring = self.scoring_metric,
                                          cv = np.shape(self.Y)[0], # sets the fold size for cross-val. cv = # of samples is essentially LOO CV.
                                          verbose = 0)

# print out some info to get a better idea of the training data
print "model.X_scaled"
print type(model.X_scaled[0][0]) # this is getting the type of one of the elements of X_scaled
print np.shape(model.X_scaled)
print model.X_scaled.tolist()

print "model.Y_scaled"
print type(model.Y_scaled) # this is getting the type of the entire arry structure
print np.shape(model.Y_scaled)
print model.Y_scaled

# fit GridSearchCV on the training data
search.fit(model.X_scaled, model.Y_scaled)
```

When this code is run, I get the resulting output:

```
model.X_scaled
<type 'numpy.float64'>
(81, 16)
model.Y_scaled
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
(81,)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SurrogateModel.py", line 416, in <module>
    self_test()
  File "SurrogateModel.py", line 409, in self_test
    model.train()
  File "SurrogateModel.py", line 350, in train
    search.fit(model.X_scaled, model.Y_scaled)
  File "/home/jack/Software/Python/anaconda2/envs/xs1opt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/grid_search.py", line 804, in fit
    return self._fit(X, y, ParameterGrid(self.param_grid))
  File "/home/jack/Software/Python/anaconda2/envs/xs1opt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/grid_search.py", line 553, in _fit
    for parameters in parameter_iterable
  File "/home/jack/Software/Python/anaconda2/envs/xs1opt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 800, in __call__
    while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
  File "/home/jack/Software/Python/anaconda2/envs/xs1opt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 658, in dispatch_one_batch
    self._dispatch(tasks)
  File "/home/jack/Software/Python/anaconda2/envs/xs1opt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 566, in _dispatch
    job = ImmediateComputeBatch(batch)
  File "/home/jack/Software/Python/anaconda2/envs/xs1opt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 180, in __init__
    self.results = batch()
  File "/home/jack/Software/Python/anaconda2/envs/xs1opt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 72, in __call__
    return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "/home/jack/Software/Python/anaconda2/envs/xs1opt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/cross_validation.py", line 1531, in _fit_and_score
    estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
  File "/home/jack/Software/Python/anaconda2/envs/xs1opt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py", line 193, in fit
    fit(X, y, sample_weight, solver_type, kernel, random_seed=seed)
  File "/home/jack/Software/Python/anaconda2/envs/xs1opt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py", line 251, in _dense_fit
    max_iter=self.max_iter, random_seed=random_seed)
  File "sklearn/svm/libsvm.pyx", line 59, in sklearn.svm.libsvm.fit (sklearn/svm/libsvm.c:1576)
  File "/home/jack/Software/Python/anaconda2/envs/xs1opt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 78, in wrapper
    "{0}".format(str(converter)))
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <type 'float'>
```

The stack trace is a bit confusing to me. sklearn makes it all the way to the "fit" call to libsvm, but then a Pandas package raises a TypeError because it can't convert a series object to a float? I looked in the pandas series.py module and found additional context for where the TypeError is being raised:

```
# in pandas/core/series.py
def _coerce_method(converter):
""" install the scalar coercion methods """

def wrapper(self):
    if len(self) == 1:
        return converter(self.iloc[0])
    raise TypeError("cannot convert the series to "
                    "{0}".format(str(converter)))

return wrapper
```

I don't understand how this Pandas function is being called when neither of the data structures I'm passing to scikit-learn are pandas objects. In the code I've provided, they're both ndarrays, but I've tried passing them as plain lists only to get the same TypeError. Pandas **is** used earlier in the code to read data from a csv into a DataFrame, but the data is converted to ndarrays before being put into X_scaled and Y_scaled.

The annoying thing is that this very nearly exact same code runs perfectly fine in the script which preceded this one. The version of the code in which I have this problem is basically refactored from the script, but this functionality, training a gridsearch object on the training data, remains mostly unchanged.

Any suggestions on what might be happening here are greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: what is the datatype of `Y_scaled`?

Comment: `Y_scaled` is an ndarray, too